# Best settings for Android camera to capture LCD?

Tags: android, android-camera

I notice the Android camera adjusts its settings according to light conditions.

I'm trying to capture the screen of an LCD and notice that sometimes the light adjustment is unfortunate leading to loss in information.

Do these settings even matter? I don't notice that much change, except for exposure compensation.

I currently have the following settings set:

```
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        // Minimal exposure compensation to better quality of information
        params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMinExposureCompensation());
        // What's the best white balance for capturing LCDs?
        params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_SHADE);
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
        // For my purpose I don't need antibanding..
        params.setAntibanding(Camera.Parameters.ANTIBANDING_OFF);
        params.setZoom(0);
        // Focus mode fixed
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);

        // Fix the auto exposure
        if (params.isAutoExposureLockSupported())
            params.setAutoExposureLock(true);
        // Fix the white balance
        if (params.isAutoWhiteBalanceLockSupported())
            params.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings proved to work well for capturing LCDs, after applying the parameters with camera.setParameters(params), which I had forgotten.